# Is this phrase right?

Tags: localization, internationalization

I'm developing an application in English, but I'm not a native English speaker.  The following message will appear when my program is processing so users have to wait until the process ends.

"now processing..don't terminate this program"

I don't know if the phrase is used the right way in English. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Suitable for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so this would be like the "saving... don't turn off the device"?

Comment: You would probably find enough programmers on http://english.stackexchange.com/ to give you a reliable answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a fan of "Processing, please wait".

A progress bar or some other visual indicator can also help ensure your users wait while giving them something to look at while they are waiting.